# Continuous integration architecture with git

Tags: git

I'm trying to figure out suitable solution for continuous integration architecture with git.

The method for checking a new feature is to upload it to one production server (out of dozens) and then check feature behavior. If the feature is working fine, we will merge it to master and then upload the same version to all of the servers.
Currently, we are working with git flow (master-develop-release-feature-hotfix branches). I'm thinking it has some drawbacks for the continuous flow described above.

What would you do?

(Perhaps Git Forking Workflow?)

Answer (score 0):

Continuous integration typically involves using a commit hook to trigger an automatic build and test cycle. It's not usually much affected by what type of branches you create. If you're only doing manual testing then it's not going to be nearly as easy or effective, but in principle you could have your CI software automatically set your code up on a test server and then wait for a human to provide feedback before automatically merging.